# Single line select using string builder or Stored Procedure

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, plsql

I have a lot of single line select queries in my application with multiple joins spanning 5-6 tables. These queries are generated based on many conditions based on input from a form etc using String Builders. However my team lead who happens to be a sql developer has asked me to convert those single line queries to Stored Procedures.

Is there any advantage of converting the single line select queries to backend and performing all the if and else there as SP.

Comment: You generate the queries "based on many conditions". How difficult would it be to test for these conditions in the database (in a stored procedure)?

Comment: @HansKesting well thats quiet tough. but does this enhance performance in cases of long select statements spanning 5-6tables

Answer (score 2):

One advantage of having all your sql part in stored procedures is that you keep your queries in one place that is database so it would a lot easier to change or modify without making a lot of changes in application layer or front end layer.

Besides DBA's or SQL develoeprs could fine tune the SQL's if it is stored in database procedures. You could keep all your functions/stored procedures in a package which would be better in terms of performance and organizing your objects(similar way of creating packages in Java). And of course in packages you could restrict direct access to its objects.

This is more of team's or department policy where to keep the sql part whether in front end or in database itself and of course like @Gimby mentioned, many people could have different views.

*Update 1*

If you have a select statement which returns something use a function, if you have INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE or similar stuff like sending emails or other business rules then use a procedure and call these from front end by passing parameters.

Comment: for multiple sql statements its fine. but does it really make sense if its single line query. Splly when I have to check if user input a value A or B in the form and join it accordingly in the query.

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar IMHO use a function/procedure and call from front end. Perhaps in future if someone would like to modify, they can modify in function or procedure without touching application code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that is a question that will result in many different answers based on many different personal opinions.

Its business logic you are talking about here in any case, in -my- opinion that belongs in the application layer. But I know a whole club of Oracle devs who wholeheartedly disagree with me.

Answer (score 0):

If your use PreparedStatement in java then there is no big differense in performance between
java queries and stored procedures. (If your use Statement in java, then your have a problem).

But Stored Procedure is a good way to organize and reuse your sql code. Your can group them in packages, your can change them without java compilation and your DBA or SQL spetialist can tune them.